# How to simulate onclickout event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'd like to somehow be able to define with JavaScript an `onclickout` event. That is something that happens when the user clicks anywhere else that the element in question.
I tried with `onblur` but it just don't seem to work :/

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the jQuery help, but the logic is the same if you prefer without it.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    var condition = $(event.target).parents(/* element_in_question */).length;
        if (condition == 0) {   // 0 means the event is not originated from the element in question
            // Do what you need to do
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

document.onclick = function() {
    alert('click somewhere else');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/C9CL3/).

This will send a click anywhere (except on `#click`) to the `document.onclick` handler, which will fire the `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable, clickedin, on an element's click handler, and then have a click handler for the document that is checking if clickedin is true, and if it is, handle appropriately.

There may be a better way to accomplish the same end, though.